# Typescript Windows cmd shell * bug TS5063 watch

Tags: typescript, cmd, watch

I am trying to run the command

```
tsc *.ts --watch --target ES5
```

in the Windows cmd shell, but it does not find my file app.ts. If I enter

```
 tsc app.ts --watch --target ES5
```

it works. So it's the * symbol which is not recognized by the cmd shell. Does anyone has already got this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: The cmd shell is not like a POSIX shell that expands wildcards for you. The application has to do that.

Comment: cmd does wildcard expansion for its own built-in commands such as `dir`, but not for external commands.

Comment: ok thank you Eryksun I didn't know the POSIX shell :)
I will take a look on it;)

Comment: POSIX is an OS spec that's typically followed by Unix and Unix-like systems such as Linux and BSD. GNU bash is probably the most common POSIX shell nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way than using `tsc` with arguments, is to create `tsconfig.json` file in the same directory as your project. You can tweak much more settings there.

Insert this basic config in the `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./"
  }
}
```

Now you just run `tsc` without any arguments and it will compile any `ts` file in the dirs or subdirs where `tsconfig.json` is located.

Little more advanced config can look like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./out"
  }
}
```

This will compile/transpile every `ts` file in `src` dir into `out` dir. Project structure looks like this:

```
app/
  - app.ts
  - myFunction.ts
out/
  - app.js
  - myFunction.js
tsconfig.json
```

Comment: Hi Erik thank you for your reply.
Indeed it works but as I made a little project and I put all my .ts file not in a folder of my project I had to make
`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "",
    "outDir": ""
  }
}`

Thanks anyway;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have `tsc` watch your files, you actually don't need to include `*.ts`.  You can just navigate to the directory that contains `tsconfig.json` and run `tsc --watch` and it will run indefinitely and watch any TypeScript files in that directory or any of its child directories and transpile them as it detects changes.  Additionally, in your question you added `--target ES5`, you can just put that in your `tsconfig.json` file.  I've included a pretty standard example that I think would work for what you are trying to do.

`{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}`

Just as a final addition, I have seen several blog posts that claim that you need the `*.ts` argument (such as this one: http://michaelcrump.net/quick-tip-with-typescript-and-vscode/ which was published in May of 2015) so it's possible that this has been changed at some point in the last few years.  FYI I'm running version 2.3.3 (run `tsc --version`) and I can confirm that `tsc --watch` does what you're looking for with this version.

Hope this helps!